# As a president of my university rocket club. Would it be easier for me to get an internship/job in an aeronautical company?

Tags: aerospace-engineering

Became president of a rocket club. Since I'm kind of new to this whole internship/job stuff (haven't had any in the past) so I'm wondering if this would contribute towards it?

Also, what should I do to really land one as a president of a rocket club? I know ofc that I will have to do typical rocketry stuff, having some workshops, inviting experts in rocketry for talks, hosting rocket events in my uni. But besides these things that I have mentioned. What else would I have to improve my chances of getting an internship/job in an aeronautical company?

Comment: How is it this has been asked twice....and not closed?

Comment: @morbo because some want the points by answering both and setting a good example for the rest of us...

Answer (score 1):

In itself this can be either good or bad. If you can use it to demonstrate an active interest in rocketry, plus some leadership and organizational skills, that is obviously good.

But don't try something like this just "because it will look good on your application". Don't forget that if you get an interview at an aerospace company, quite likely your interviewer will have spent some time working on "real" rockets and also have some management experience, so expect to end up talking about what you did *in detail.*

It is usually obvious to an experienced interview whether you are just "saying what you think they want to hear" and/or talking technical BS, or whether you *really* contributed something to the club.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely helps, but your relevant coursework and grades are a large (if not larger) factor. Apply early and to as many opportunities as you can.

Are there any competitions with other school's "rocket clubs"? Winning awards at those would help.

If your school has a career center, utilize that as well to polish your resume.

Answer (score 0):

leadership is important and your being president shows leadership.  It's the kicker over other candidates with similar classes and grades.